# Кроссдоменный запрос и обработка ответа на клиенте при помощи JSONP

Tags: javascript, cors, jsonp

Пытаюсь интегрировать api со стороннего сайта на свой (пока что localhost). Бьюсь с политикой cors, у сайта есть api, но вытянуть данные с его помощью никак не получается.
Код:

```
function mob(){
var scriptt = document.createElement("script");
    scriptt.src = "https://anydomen.com/api/info.php? 
indicator=github.com&pretty=1&key=ksadi223&callback=respons";
    document.body.appendChild(scriptt);
window['respons'] = function(data){
  console.log('data = ' + data);
  return data;
}
}
```

Я так понимаю нужно обработать ответ сервера, потому как ошибок нет, есть только предупреждения, но именно в "обработать" и не получается сейчас.

Comment: А «сторонний сайт» обещал доступ к апи?

Comment: У стороннего сайте есть доступ к определенным операция по api

Comment: Прямо по jsonp доступ? Вообще-то cors к jsonp не применяется, так что мне непонятно над чем вы бьётесь.

Comment: Доступ по get запросу с параметрами в которых есть ключ, который в свою очередь генерит этот сторонний сайт. Обычным get запросом не получилось воспользоваться, браузер выдает ошибку, т.к. это запрос с другого домена и ругается на cors политику.

Comment: Таки в чём же конкретно проблема? Вы смотрели в инструментах разработчика что возвращает ваш запрос?

Comment: Ничего не возвращает если создаю скрипт с путём как в коде выше. Попробовал с api Яндекса, он вернул данные как и должен был.
Сервис с которым я мучаюсь написан на php, это может играть роль?

Comment: Таки сервис обещал работу по jsonp или нет? Если обещал, вам прямая дорога в техподдержку, если нет, то не судьба

Comment: Сервер должен вернуть json объект, но не возвращает.
Про jsonp говорю потому что запрос в виде тега с урлом в котором параметры.

Comment: Сам сервис - https://pulsedive.com/api/?q=indicators. В саппорт написал уже, пока молчат.

Comment: Не нашёл у них в документации ничего про jsonp

Comment: jsonp это ведь универсальное решение, которое должно работать даже если явно не указано в документации, разве нет? Я пробовал простым get запросом, но браузер выдает ошибку о неправильных заголовках запроса и нарушении политики cors, заголовки пробовал устанавливать, не помогло(возможно неправильные использовал).

Comment: Ошибка из консоли: Main.js:45 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.anydomain.com/api.php with MIME type application/json

Comment: нет. Jsonp это вводящее в заблуждение название банального скрипта и вовсе не обязано работать везде.